# order admin list by username

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to order the users list by username. This is not working.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['username']
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The code is executing because if I remove the register method, it throws an error. 
I need to do this because I have another admin with:

```
list_filter = [
        'user',
        'content_type',
        'action_flag'
    ]
```

and username here is not being ordered, so it is almost imposible to search a user.

I'm using django 1.8

My ModelAdmin is:

class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
date_hierarchy = 'action_time'
search_fields = ['user__username']
readonly_fields = LogEntry._meta.get_all_field_names()
readonly_fields = [x for x in readonly_fields if x[-3:] == '_id' and x[:-3] not in readonly_fields]

list_filter = [
    'user',
    'content_type',
    'action_flag'
]


search_fields = [
    'object_repr',
    'change_message'
]


list_display = [
    'action_time',
    'user',
    'content_type',
    'object_link',
    'action_flag',
    'change_message',
]

def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return False

def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return request.user.is_superuser and request.method != 'POST'

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False

def object_link(self, obj):
    if obj.action_flag == DELETION:
        link = escape(obj.object_repr) + u' (%s)' % obj.object_id
    else:
        ct = obj.content_type
        link = u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
            reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (ct.app_label, ct.model), args=[obj.object_id]),
            escape(obj.object_repr),
        )
    return link
object_link.allow_tags = True
object_link.admin_order_field = 'object_repr'
object_link.short_description = u'object'
```

Comment: Can you show the error? Is there one? Or perhaps the data being used for testing?

Comment: If you're ordering for convenience in searching, why aren't you using `search_fields` instead?

Comment: Are you trying to filter a model in your admin based off of the username of the user? What you're doing in the code you've shared is set the ordering of the User model - not the models you've created (the admin classes are separate for each model, ordering won't carry between them)

Comment: yes it is for the LogEntry model. I want the list_filter user field to be ordered by the user name.

Comment: Can you share your `ModelAdmin` for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order a model based on the value of a relationship it has, you do that via the `ModelAdmin` for that model, not the related model (if a model has three relationships all with ordering provided, how would it order that object?). In your case, this means ordering on `LogEntryAdmin`, not `UserAdmin` - even if you want to order by the `username`.

```
class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # Like elsewhere in Django, we use __ to traverse relationships
    ordering = ['user__username']
    date_hierarchy = 'action_time'
    search_fields = ['user__username']
    readonly_fields = LogEntry._meta.get_all_field_names()
    readonly_fields = [x for x in readonly_fields if x[-3:] == '_id' and x[:-3] not in readonly_fields]
```

This means you no longer need the following ([The default ordering on `User` for admin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L65) is by username anyways):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ['username']
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```